# group headers in Jqgrid treeGridModel

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

i want to make the Group Headers in Jqgrid.
My Jqgrid has **TreeGridModel='adjacency'**.
Can AnyOne tell me How to To do It.I have searched alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Trirand](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3agroupingheadar#groupheaders_element_options).
you can use

```
  jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
  useColSpanStyle: true, 
  groupHeaders:[
    {startColumnName: 'name of model', numberOfColumns: 3, titleText: 'title'}

  ]
});
```